# SAS else if clause confusion

Tags: if-statement, sas

I'm running the following code:

```
data new;  
set old;    
    if visits=. then band='Poor';  
    else if visits=1 or visits=2 then band='Low';  
    else band='High';  
run;
```

My confusion is when the else if statement is changed to:

```
else if visits=1 or 2 then band='Low';
```

Why does the value `Low` appear as the band for cases where visits are greater than 2 instead of `High`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `if` statement is faulty in this case:

```
else if visits=1 or 2 then band='Low';
```

You are mistakenly assuming that this is effectively:

```
if visits is 1, or visits is 2 then ...
```

In fact, this is actually:

```
if visits is 1, or 2 is true then ...
```

So you are saying does `2 = true`, which it does (all non-zero values are implicitly true).  Effectively your final `else` statement (for `High`) is always ignored because the `else if` will always be true.

Stick with your original statement, which does exactly what you expect it to:

```
else if visits=1 or visits=2 then band='Low';
```

Comment: Good explanation. Missing values are also false. So suggest "all non-zero non-missing values are true". Also worth pointing out the IN() operator is an alternative: else if visits IN(1,2) then ...

Comment: Also worth emphasizing is that this value of "all non-zero non-missing values are true" is the result of a boolean operation, not the value of 'visits'. Therefore, if you move up this condition to the front: if visits=1 or 2 then band='Low';
All of your band will be 'Low'. There is no chance for downstream 'else' to perform.